# How to restrict mySQL queries to not affect server and take it down?

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration, load

There are times that some heavy queries increase server load and after sometime both CPU and Memory reaches 100%.

This is `my.cnf` configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
expire_logs_days= 2

pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/storage/mysql

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/storage/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/storage/mysql/mysql-slow.log

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover-options         = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/storage/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 2048

innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size=500M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
# recently added for compression, omit it if mysql has problems with it
innodb_file_format=Barracuda

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0


collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[client]
default-character-set   = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set   = utf8mb4
```

The server has 6 Cores with 16 GB of RAM. Any suggestion to restrict `MySQL` and make it safe?

---

**EDIT-1**
This is one of the slow queries that took 4.3 Secs from `MySQL` to return the data and has examined about 3 Million rows:

```
# Time: 190107  6:22:30
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Thread_id: 204732  Schema: my_db  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 4.306051  Lock_time: 0.000058  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 3253235
# Rows_affected: 0
SET timestamp=1546842150;
SELECT ((old_credit + (1*amount))/10) credit
FROM `credits`
WHERE user_id=' ' or user_id=(SELECT user_id FROM accounts WHERE email=' ')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The query is created by a front-end BI application (it can be changed to some extent).

Indexes of the table is:

```
MariaDB [my_db]> show index from credits;
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| credits |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |     2014915 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| credits |          1 | credit_id  |            1 | credit_id   | A         |     2014915 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| credits |          1 | user_id    |            1 | user_id     | A         |      134327 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**EDIT-2:**

```
Database changed
MariaDB [my_db]> show index from accounts;
+-------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| accounts |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id          | A         |      486034 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| accounts |          1 | user_id             |            1 | user_id    | A         |      486034 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| accounts |          1 | email_idx           |            1 | email       | A         |      486034 |      190 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| accounts |          1 | user_id_email_phone |            1 | user_id    | A         |      486034 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| accounts |          1 | user_id_email_phone |            2 | email       | A         |      486034 |       40 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| accounts |          1 | user_id_email_phone |            3 | phone       | A         |      486034 |       15 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What else is running on that machine?  The config implies that you should not be running out of RAM for MySQL.  As for CPU:  That is almost always due to missing indexes and/or poorly formulated queries.  Let's see a "slow" query to discuss.

Comment: @RickJames, Could you take a look at the `EDIT-1` part of the question? It's good to note that there are other processes that are consuming memory and CPU like `influxDB`, `Docker`, `grafana` and so.

Comment: Could you post SHOW INDEX FROM accounts: ? 
For a little safety, in your my.cnf   max_connect_errors=10   rather than 1 million to stop hacker/cracker at 10 attempts to break in rather than after they have made 1 million password attempts.

Comment: @WilsonHauck The question is updated with `EDIT-2` part. Could you take a look at it. tnx

Comment: @ALH Could you post results of SHOW CREATE TABLE credits;  and SCT accounts;  AND results of EXPLAIN SELECT ((old_cretdit ........  Thanks

Comment: @ALH Have you tried Rick James LAST refactored query that uses JOIN?  Should be nearly instantaneous if your indexes exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really mean `= ' '`?  That is checking for the string being *one* character long, namely a space.

`OR` is a performance killer, so let's get rid of it by using `UNION`:

```
    ( SELECT  id, ((old_credit + (amount))/10) AS credit
            FROM  `credits`
            WHERE  user_id=' '
            ORDER BY  id DESC
            LIMIT  1;
    )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT  c.id, ((c.old_credit + (c.amount))/10) AS credit
            FROM  `credits` AS c
            JOIN  accounts AS a  ON a.user_id = c.user_id
            WHERE  a.email=' ' 
            ORDER BY  c.id DESC
            LIMIT  1;
    )
    ORDER BY  id DESC
    LIMIT  1;
```

Indexes needed:

```
credits:  (user_id, id)
accounts: (email, user_id)
```

This might be even faster, and it eliminates the extra column (id) that the above solution has.

```
SELECT ((c2.old_credit + (c2.amount))/10) AS credit
  FROM (
    ( SELECT  id
            FROM  `credits`
            WHERE  user_id=' '
            ORDER BY  id DESC
            LIMIT  1;
    )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT  c.id
            FROM  `credits` AS c
            JOIN  accounts AS a  ON a.user_id = c.user_id
            WHERE  a.email=' ' 
            ORDER BY  c.id DESC
            LIMIT  1;
    )
    ORDER BY  id DESC
    LIMIT  1;
  ) AS x
  JOIN credits c2  ON c2.id = x.id
```

The above `INDEXes` are needed here, too.  (And I am assuming that `credits` has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.)

`Rows_examined: 3253235` will probably decrease to under 10.

As for how to prevent naughty queries, `MariaDB 10.1+`, but not `MySQL`, has `max_statement_time`.

<strike>I see no reason why you would be hitting 100% Memory.</strike> (see comment.)  But each copy of that query would probably chew up one core for 4.3 seconds.  (Either of my versions probably won't chew up even 4.3 *milliseconds*.)

Do you want help with other slow queries?

Comment: I really appreciate for your time, I'll apply this query optimization and give feedback later on. Just so you know, unfortunately queries like `user_id = ' '` are forced by a UI application.

Comment: And I hit 100% memory because of many similar concurrent queries.

Comment: @ALH - up to 500 connections, each creating one (or more) tmp tables of up to 32MB each -- Yes that could blow out RAM.  Consider lowering each of those settings as a preventative measure.